# How do I return the box height to original state when clicked again in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.box').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $btn = $(this);
            $btn.toggleClass('opened');

            var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 100;
            $(this).stop().animate({ height: heights }, 800);
            //$(".sync_store_info_input_holder").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 73px;
    width: 269px;
    margin: 40px 42px 0px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 73px;
}
```

The function above works fine but whenever the box is clicked open and click closed the height of the box is a bit more than the initial state.  It's not a CSS issue but it seems that the height 100 in the script doesn't toggle.  How can I make it so that when the box is closed the height goes back to the original state?

Problem:

It appears that the height in the function `100` remains even after the box is clicked shut.  How can I make it so that when the box is closed the original height of the box is restored.  The height of the box is in the .box class, which is 275px.

Comment: Yes, it does toggle. http://jsfiddle.net/kBu3N/

Comment: if you console.log($btn.height()) initially, does it say your original height is actually 100?

Comment: @user2736012 yes of course it does but the height is longer when clicked open and then closed.

Comment: I don't really understand you. Do you want the box to have a height of 275px when closed and a height of 300px when opened?

Comment: Wait, you're setting it to `100` and then wondering why it's resized to `100`?

Comment: @user2736012 that's what I'm thinking as well..

Comment: it should be ? 300 : 275; in that case..

Comment: Do you understand the basics of how CSS works, and how elements are styled via JavaScript?

Comment: You guys are not understanding.  When the box is opened it extends 100px, right? But when it's closed it doesn't close all the way.

Comment: If you wanted it to go to `73`, then why were you setting it to `100`? I guess I need to say it again. You really need to learn the basics. It's quite selfish to ask others to spend time helping you when you've not bothered to put forth the basic efforts to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your height to 73.

Change 100 to 73:

```
var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 73;
```

Comment: @codingaround Review the CSS he posted.  His height in the css class is 73.  By setting it to 73 he is able to solve his problem.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the best solution, but depending on the div height this works:

jQuery/JavaScript:

```
var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 200;
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christianheinrichs/xjLtwm9v/2/)

Comment: It seems that the height in the script: 100 remains even after it's closed which is overwriting it.

Comment: Which height exactly? the `.box` one or the `$btn` one?

Comment: Since you didn't answer I made the test myself and put it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3eYg/). I don't see 100 at all, but 200, 300 and for whatever reason 337.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Using your solution made it even worse.  And I don't understand that since in your fiddle it works but not on my thing.

Comment: What exactly is worse now? Did you properly include the jQuery library? Not on jsFiddle obviously, but on your setup.